# How to log in to Vimeo after authenticating

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, vimeo

I am quite new to android dev so pardon the probably simple question. I am following the [README](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/44058db2a7297f371897815e04d1714359242b99/README.md) for vimeo-networking-java and I'm not sure how to log in after authenticating with client credentials.

```kotlin
val configuration = VimeoApiConfiguration.Builder(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, listOf(ScopeType.PUBLIC, ScopeType.PRIVATE, ScopeType.VIDEO_FILES))
            .withCertPinning(false)
            .build()

//      Initialize the authenticator instance with the configuration and the api client.
        val authenticator = Authenticator(configuration)

        val apiClient = VimeoApiClient(configuration, authenticator)

        authenticator.authenticateWithClientCredentials(
            vimeoCallback(
                onSuccess = {
                    Log.d(TAG, "initVimeoAuthenticator: logged in: ${authenticator.currentAccount?.isLoggedIn}") // false
                    Log.d(TAG, "initVimeoAuthenticator: accessToken: ${authenticator.currentAccount?.accessToken}") // returns token
                    
                },
                onError = {
                    Log.d(TAG, "initVimeoAuthenticator: error: ${it.message}")
                }
            )
        )
```

Then, when I make a request, I get a 401 error saying "You must provide a valid authenticated access token."

```kotlin
apiClient.fetchVideoList(
            uri = VIDEOS_ENDPOINT_URI,
            fieldFilter = fields,
            queryParams = null,
            cacheControl = CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK,
            callback = vimeoCallback<VideoList>(
                onSuccess = {
                    val video = it.data.data?.get(0)
                    ...
                },
...
```

How do I login/provide the token?